# Will the Sharp Architecture ModelBinder properly constitute an object using a jQuery ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, modelbinders, sharp-architecture

Do you know if it's possible to make an AJAX request and have the model binder properly constitute an object based on the parameter provided?

For example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../Create',
    data: ( {
        'SkillTypeRequest.Id':                0,
        'SkillTypeRequest.Event.Id':        eventId,
        'SkillTypeRequest.SkillType.Id':    skillTypeId,
        'SkillTypeRequest.Division.Id':     divisionId
    } ),
    success: function (data) { addSkillTypeRow( data ); }
});
```

The test controller action is:

public ActionResult Create(SkillTypeRequest request) {
    return Json( request );
}

At the moment, this fails in the model binder because it's trying to assign null to the SkillTypeRequest.Id. Before I investigate further, just want to make sure this is even possible to begin with or does Sharp/MVC only allow this type of binding through forms?